Multiple inheritance in Rust
I'm just starting in the Rust (come from python and C#) world and I know this question has been asked many times, but I'm struggling to understand the answers as they are very generic (Foo, Bar, Baz). I'm not even sure if what I need is achievable in Rust.
I need a class to inherit a method from its parent and grand-parent as well and force it to implement functions defined in its parent.
Case:
As you can see in the Code section bellow, Days30BondCounter and Days30ECounter structs return the day_count with the same expresion. All the difference is in how d1 and d2 is calculated.
My Idea is to create a Days30 abstract class that inherits from DayCounter but that requires implementing get_d1 and get_d2 functions. So that Days30 looks something like
trait Days30 : DayCounter {
    fn get_d1(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32;
    fn get_d2(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32;

    fn day_count(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i64 {
        let d1 = self.get_d1(start_date, end_date);
        let d2 = self.get_d2(start_date, end_date);
        (360 * (end_date.year() - start_date.year()) + 30 * ((end_date.month() - start_date.month()) as i32) + d2 - d1) as i64
    }
}

struct Days30BondCounter;
impl Days30 for Days30BondCounter { // this fails
    fn get_d1(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32 {
        1 // d1 logic
    }
    fn get_d2(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32 {
        2 // d2 logic
    }
}

Code:
use chrono::{Datelike, NaiveDate, TimeDelta};
use std::cmp::min;

trait DayCounter { // Base Class
    fn day_count(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i64;

    fn day_count_vector(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_dates: &Vec<NaiveDate>) -> Vec<i64> {
        let mut result: Vec<i64> = Vec::with_capacity(end_dates.len()); // Replace with VLA
        for end_date in end_dates {
            result.push(self.day_count(start_date, *end_date));
        }
        result
    }

}

struct ActualCounter; // Simple child
impl DayCounter for ActualCounter {
    fn day_count(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i64 {
        let duration: TimeDelta = end_date.signed_duration_since(start_date);
        duration.num_days()    
    }
}

struct Days30BondCounter; // This is currently a Child. I'd like it to inherit from Days30 which inherits from DayCounter
impl DayCounter for Days30BondCounter {
    fn day_count(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i64 {
        let mut d1: i32 = start_date.day() as i32;
        d1 = min(d1, 30);
        let mut d2: i32 = end_date.day() as i32;
        if d1 > 29 {
            d2 = min(d2, 30);
        }

        (360 * (end_date.year() - start_date.year()) + 30 * ((end_date.month() - start_date.month()) as i32) + d2 - d1) as i64
    }
}

struct Days30ECounter; // This is currently a Child. I'd like it to inherit from Days30 which inherits from DayCounter
impl DayCounter for Days30ECounter {
    fn day_count(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i64 {
        let d1: i32 = min(start_date.day(), 30) as i32;
        let d2: i32 = min(end_date.day(), 30) as i32;
        
        (360 * (end_date.year() - start_date.year()) + 30 * ((end_date.month() - start_date.month()) as i32) + d2 - d1) as i64
    }
}

Extra Info:

DayCounter is like the base class. Any implementation must define a way to count days between 2 dates in day_count method.

get_d1 and get_d2 are Days30 only methods (non useful in ActualCounter implementation). Its results give d1 and d2 to be used in Days30 implementation of day_count



"a Days30 abstract class that inherits from DayCounter but that requires implementing get_d1 and get_d2 functions" - but Rust doesn't have classes, nor "inheritance" - you need to change your way of thinking, instead of trying to code C#/Java in Rust.

Sounds like you should encapsulate common logic into a function.

@kmdreko But that would require to call the function in each implementation And also have to implement day_count instead of just implementing get_d1 and get_d2.

@Dai How do you deal with this in Rust then? I have like 4 other implementations for Day30 like "classes". Repeating code doesn't sound like a good idea.

@OliverMohrBonometti It would help if you would explain what DayCounter and get_d1 and get_d2 (and the rest) are meant to be...

Instead of defining day_count on Days30, which is unrelated to day_count on DayCounter try implementing it. Generically, i.e. impl<T: Days30> DayCounter for T {...}.

I'll start by requesting everyone read this article. And some C2 articles too. (i.e. anyone who thinks "inheritance" (without further qualification) is a solution - or even the default solution - to a delegation problem - probably hasn't used inheritance enough in their life such that they finally grok that it isn't a good solution  )

With that out of the way, my interpretation of your mission statement: "My idea is to create..." is this C#:
abstract class DayCounter
{
    public virtual Int64 DayCount()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// 

sealed class ActualCounter : DayCounter
{
}

//

abstract class Days30 : DayCounter
{
    public override Int64 DayCount()
    {
        // do stuff with `this.GetD1()` and `this.GetD2()`.
    }

    protected abstract Int32 GetD1();
    protected abstract Int32 GetD2();
}

sealed class Days30BondCounter : Days30
{
    protected override Int32 GetD1() { ... }
    protected override Int32 GetD2() { ... }
}

sealed class Days30ECounter : Days30
{
    protected override Int32 GetD1() { ... }
    protected override Int32 GetD2() { ... }
}

...and I'll say this already has a code-smell. IMO, the GetD1 and GetD2 methods in Days30 are unnecessarily exposed private implementation concern of Days30; if Days30 wants to delegate those methods out that's fine, but using inheritance here (with protected abstract) methods seems like a bad idea to me; chiefly, any subclassing of Days30 then introduces more implications compared to if class Days30 just had its own service-type interface for those delegated methods.
Whereas this (below) is how things look if we introduce interface IDays30Backend for delegation - note how Days30 is now no-longer abstract, and is also to provide its own default/baseline implementation of IDays30Backend if its ctor call-site fails to provide one (SomeDefaultDays30BackendImpl).
sealed class Days30 : DayCounter
{
    private readonly IDays30Backend backend;

    public Days30( IDays30Backend? backend )
    {
        this.backend = backend ?? new SomeDefaultDays30BackendImpl();
    }
}

interface IDays30Backend
{
    Int32 GetD1();
    Int32 GetD2();
}

sealed class Days30BondCounter : IDays30Backend
{
    public Int32 GetD1() { ... }
    public Int32 GetD2() { ... }
}

sealed class Days30ECounter : IDays30Backend
{
    public Int32 GetD1() { ... }
    public Int32 GetD2() { ... }
}

...and if you think about it, the same can be said about DayCounter; so without getting into too much detail, DayCounter could be a C# interface type too (don't forget that C# supports default-implementations of interface members now):
interface IDayCounter
{
    virtual Int64 DayCount()
    {
        // (default impl)
    }
}

sealed class Days30 : IDayCounter
{
    // etc
}

sealed class ActualCounter : IDayCounter
{
    // etc
}

...and notice how suddenly we're not using inheritance at all anymore!

...so if we take the above re-composition in C# it becomes easier to translate over to Rust:
use chrono::{Datelike, NaiveDate, TimeDelta, Utc};
use std::cmp::min;

//

trait DayCounter {

    fn day_count(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i64;

    fn day_count_vector(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_dates: &Vec<NaiveDate>) -> Vec<i64> {
        let mut result: Vec<i64> = Vec::with_capacity(end_dates.len()); // Replace with VLA
        for end_date in end_dates {
            result.push(self.day_count(start_date, *end_date));
        }
        result
    }
}

////////////////////
// ActualCounter:

struct ActualCounter {
    
}

impl DayCounter for ActualCounter {
    fn day_count(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i64 {
        let duration: TimeDelta = end_date.signed_duration_since(start_date);
        duration.num_days()    
    }
}

////////////////////
// Days30Counter (nee `Days30`), with `Days30Backend`

struct Days30Counter {
//  backend: dyn Days30Backend
    backend: Box<dyn Days30Backend>
}

impl DayCounter for Days30Counter {
    
    fn day_count(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i64 {
        /*
        let mut d1: i32 = start_date.day() as i32;
        d1 = min(d1, 30);
        let mut d2: i32 = end_date.day() as i32;
        if d1 > 29 {
            d2 = min(d2, 30);
        }
        */
        
        let d1 = self.backend.get_d1(start_date, end_date);
        let d2 = self.backend.get_d2(start_date, end_date);

        (360 * (end_date.year() - start_date.year()) + 30 * ((end_date.month() - start_date.month()) as i32) + d2 - d1) as i64
    }
}

trait Days30Backend {
    
    fn get_d1(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32;
    fn get_d2(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32;
}

//

struct Days30BondCounter {
    
}

impl Days30Backend for Days30BondCounter {
    
    fn get_d1(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32 {
        1 // d1 logic
    }
    fn get_d2(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32 {
        2 // d2 logic
    }
}

//

struct Days30ECounter {
    
}

impl Days30Backend for Days30ECounter {
    
    fn get_d1(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32 {
        let mut d1: i32 = start_date.day() as i32;
        d1 = min(d1, 30);
        return d1;
    }
    fn get_d2(&self, start_date: NaiveDate, end_date: NaiveDate) -> i32 {
        let d1 = self.get_d1(start_date, end_date);
        let mut d2: i32 = end_date.day() as i32;
        if d1 > 29 {
            d2 = min(d2, 30);
        }
        return d2;
    }
}

//

fn main() {

    println!("Hello, world!");
    
    let startDt: NaiveDate = Utc::now().date_naive();
    let endDt  : NaiveDate = Utc::now().date_naive();
    
    let dayCounterImpl1 = ActualCounter{};
    
    let dayCounterImpl2 = Days30Counter{
        backend: Box::new(Days30BondCounter{})
    };

    let dayCounterImpl2 = Days30Counter{
        backend: Box::new(Days30ECounter {})
    };
    
    //
    
    let result1 = dayCounterImpl1.day_count( /*startDate:*/ startDt, /*endDate:*/ endDt );
    let result2 = dayCounterImpl2.day_count( /*startDate:*/ startDt, /*endDate:*/ endDt );
    let result3 = dayCounterImpl3.day_count( /*startDate:*/ startDt, /*endDate:*/ endDt );

    println!( "result1: {}", result1 ); // 0
    println!( "result2: {}", result2 ); // 1
    println!( "result3: {}", result2 ); // 1
}

...and it compiles for me in the playground (thought prints zero for output).
(And yes, this really is the first compilable Rust program I've ever written).
